# React native Current Location not working

Tags: react-native

I am using react native, I have a problem in my code, It is always shows location Latitude : 37.6016000000, Longitude : -122.42600000, not my location, I want to show my location :

```
    constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state ={
  region:null,
  refreshing: false,
}
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  position => {
    //const initialPositiong = JSON.stringify(position);
    let regionn={

      longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      latitudeDelta:  0.45,
  longitudeDelta: 0.45,
  timestamp:  position.timestamp
    }

    this.setState({ region : regionn});
    Alert.alert('Erroooor', JSON.stringify(position));

  },
  error => Alert.alert('Error', this.state.hhh ),
  {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 2000, maximumAge: 3600000},
);
    }
      render(){
      return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <MapView

   style={styles.map}
   region={this.state.region}

 >

 </MapView>
 <Text>{this.state.region.latitude}</Text>
        </View>
        );
        }
```

Also, I tried to change to false for this enableHighAccuracy: true,

Comment: you test it in a real device or emulator

Comment: I test it in the emulator

Comment: Do I have to test it on real device ?

Comment: change your emulator lat, lng in settings or test it on real device